# how to manage lock-write mechanism in django

Tags: python, django, locking

i've been searching for a while for a way to handle the lock-write mechanism in( whenever user is updating , the record should be locked for the others ) . and i've been told that the web-frame work is responsible for this.
check this out : 
https://serverfault.com/questions/184666/how-to-configure-apache-server
my question is : 
how do i do that with django , in other words . what title should i be searching under 
this is an Emergence task . please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks on the Database are provided by your DBMS like MySql or MSSQL Server. Not your framework or webserver.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28database%29)

Comment: Not necessarily; if it's a long-term lock, eg. for a shared text editor that says "this document can't be edited because someone else is editing it already", you definitely do not want a database lock or transaction.  (The question is too vague to have any idea what he's actually asking, of course.)

Comment: True, but on his posting over at serverfault he talks about database entries.

Comment: Documents like that are still typically stored in a database.  Anyhow, throwing darts is all that can be done with a question like this...

Comment: glad that Henrik answered my question ( your the man with the most interesting topics in stackoverflow to me ) ^_^